# How do I install Canon LBP2900B printer in UBUNTU

Tags: canon

Everything done as instructed in the given URL,
[How To Install Canon LBP2900B printer in 14.04 LTS ? I tried the method for LBP2900 but it didnt work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487627/how-to-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-14-04-lts-i-tried-the-method-for-lbp2)

but I am getting "Communication Error" message.
<<
Check the followings:
-Is the printer turned on?
-Is the cable correctly connected?

> >

what should I do next? Please advice..

Answer (score 0):

Hope you tried these steps in terminal :

sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E

sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0

sudo service ccpd start

sudo service ccpd status

And finally check the printer status:

captstatusui -P LBP2900