# How to make Canon LBP2900B work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, printing, canon

I am not able to print with my Printer Canon LBP2900B even though I installed the drivers in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit PC and followed all the official documentation/tutorial. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

After clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 my Canon 2900 refused to print. I found out a solution and will now share here with my experience.

Standard method to install driver doesn't work. To install driver manually I downloaded and unpacked them from the official web-site of Canon.

The next step was to choose between the 32- or 64-bit driver. First my decision was to use 64-bit driver, because my OS is also 64-bit. But it was a mistake, 64-bit driver refused to work. So I choose 32-bit driver, unpacked and installed two packages in the following order:

```
cndrvcups-common.deb    
cndrvcups-capt.deb
```

Then I registered the printer in OS by typing in the terminal:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cups restart
sudo lpadmin -p LBP2900 -m CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59687 -E
sudo ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0
sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults
```

After the printer appears in menu I marked him as default by right click. All these time the printer must be turned off.

Then I reboot and printer start work.

But after that appears a new problem. When I shuttdown my computer it hangs during 5 minutes. It was caused by ccpd service. So I run:

```
sudo systemctl edit ccpd
```

and added new two lines to empty file:

```
[Service]    
TimeoutStopSec=4
```

Then:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl show ccpd -p TimeoutStopUSec
```

and it shows that the delay was shorted. Next reboot took only several seconds.

That's all.

Source: https://yrfiles.blogspot.in/2016/12/how-to-make-canon-lbp-2900-printing-on.html