# ubuntu 18.04 Samsung C480W printer NO COLOURS when printing

Tags: printing, samsung

This printer does not print colour when I attach it to my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04. Using recommended driver for Samsung C48x series PS.

It works correctly when I print via Windows 7 on the same laptop.

Can anybody tell me what to make it work, printing colour also on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox and type:

```
http://127.0.0.1:631/
```

In order to access CUPS and check your default printing settings.

> CUPS is the standards-based, open source printing system developed by Apple Inc. for macOS® and other UNIX®-like operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly installed your printer on Ubuntu 18.04 [check out this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033566/canon-printer-problem-on-ubuntu-18-04) open your chosen browser (Firefox, Chromium etc) and in the address bar type `http://localhost:631/`

This will open up the CUPS utility allowing you to select your printer and modify its defaults.

Select your printer then go to Administration >Set Default Options.

Under Color Mode use the drop down menu to select Color

[image]

Alternatively, go to Settings > Devices > Printers and select Additional Printer Settings... at the bottom of the screen right click on the printer and select Properties. Then move down to Job Options and select print-color-mode and select to color. Then click on <kbd>Apply</kbd> then <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still not working. Color Mode is set to colour. This issue is the same also on my friends laptop. The funny thing is that when I print to another printer of slightly different model Samsung C460W the colour printing works fine. So I'm beginning to suspekt a bug (?) in the driver. Or do you have any other suggestions?