# Unable to install Canon Laser Shot LBP2900b Laser Printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers

How to install Canon LaserShot LBP2900b Laser Printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To Install Canon LBP2900B printer in 14.04 LTS ? I tried the method for LBP2900 but it didnt work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487627/how-to-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-14-04-lts-i-tried-the-method-for-lbp2)

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page:

https://in.canon/en/support/0100459601/7?model=0017B011

Click on the download button.

The name file linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz will be downloaded, suppose in /home/user/Downloads

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
cd /home/user/Downloads
tar --xzvf linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz
cd /home/user/Downloads/linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Change **user** to your **username**